# How do I create a new .mpeg from the last 10 seconds of an original using ffmpeg or MEncoder

Tags: ffmpeg, mencoder

I have a number of .mpeg files that I only want to use the last 10 seconds of (kind of like a replay)

Is ffmpeg or MEncoder able to do this and if so can someone please help me out with the command line syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with the latest version of ffmpeg:

```
-sseof time_off     set the start time offset relative to EOF
```

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -c copy -map 0 -sseof 10 output.mpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure when it changed, but the example from Tyler does not work anymore (at least for me).

**Here** is what worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -sseof -10 -i input.avi -c copy output.avi
```